# Preview a voronoi/magic/clouds/other texture?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, node-editor

Usually, when I am using a Displace modifier on an object and want to use a texture for it, I can get a preview in the texture tab:

[image: Displace modifier texture panel]

However, when I use the texture in the node editor as a mix shader fac input (as I have been doing recently), I cannot preview the texture in the texture tab.

[image: Node editor texture panel]

How can I preview the texture in the node editor and change the contrast/brightness as I can with the Displace textures?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could preview them directly on the mesh using an emisssion shader. Node Wrangler / Node Efficiency Tools provides a hotkey for that (sadly I can't recall it.)

Comment: Ctrl Shift click on the node to be previewed (Node Wrangler Addon)

Comment: @user277143 I don't want to preview on the mesh, I want to preview the texture.

Comment: @joshsanfelici I'll try that.

Comment: @Flaeon We both mean the same thing: Ctrl Shift click (thanks, Josh) with the node wrangler addon makes the surface of the mesh be an emission shader. If you UV-unwrap a plane and have it have your material, you can preview the texture that way.

Comment: So you can't actually preview the texture? Seriously Blender?

Comment: Just change the preview window on the right side to the plane.  The node wrangler tool adds the Ctrl Shift Click shortcut (like in the compositing nodes) to preview a texture.  It's much more flexible this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't currently preview cycles textures independently in the texture tab, as far as I know, they belong to a completely different rendering system.

You can however get some kind of preview of the texture by previewing the material itself in the *Materials* tab of the *Properties Window* by expanding the preview panel and switching to a *Flat* preview object.

[image]